# How to Close/Hide Loading... in PulltoRefresh Listview programmatically

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

Loading... always shown in PulltoRefresh listview, when error in server connection. How to close it programmatically?!

```
public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) 
{
    if(true)
    {
        skip refresh                            
    }
    else
    {
        refresh
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw this project Android-PullToRefresh in github, 
When you refresh error exception , You can try mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete() , this function to close refresh loading。

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the loading animation like this:

```
mPullRefreshScrollView = (PullToRefreshScrollView) findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_scrollview);
mPullRefreshScrollView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ObservableScrollView>() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ObservableScrollView> refreshView) {
        if (true) {
          //skip refresh
            mPullRefreshScrollView.onRefreshComplete();
        } else {
          //refresh

        }
    }
});
```